Was the universal translator originally broken in the Star Trek VI 'book scene'?
When I originally saw Star Trek VI in the theatre, I distinctly remember the universal translator being broken, as the rationale for using the physical translation books to speak with the Klingons.
Every time I've watched it since then, we hear Chekov saying that the use of the translator would be recognized. But this doesn't seem to line up with the fact that the crew is clearly scrambling for the books rather than being ready for this foreseeable situation. (Also, Chekov's line sounds very much dubbed over and he's facing away from the camera.)
Was this changed, or am I remembering the theatrical release wrong? And if I am remembering it wrong, why is the crew unprepared?

This script "copy" makes no reference to the universal translator so it's possible the "dubbed" line was retconned in production to explain them not using it.

For what it's worth, Nichelle Nichols tried to get the scene rewritten because she thought it was ridiculous that, as a high-ranking communications officer, Uhura wouldn't at least be familiar with the primary language of the Federation's biggest military enemy, but Nicholas Meyer overruled her.

Per the official novelisation, records of the Klingon language were wiped from the computers records by the same mysterious hacker who forged the log of them firing a missile.

Sir," Uhura said suddenly. Spock turned at the note of panic in her tone. "The universal translator-I was just programming it for Klingonese, but it's not responding. It's coming out all garbled."
Spock moved swiftly to the communications console and swiftly ran a diagnostics; both he and Uhura read the results and gave each other a knowing look.
Even if Enterprise ran cloaked into Klingon space, she still risked detection by specially equipped listening posts inside the Klingon border. And without the translator to aid them, the risk of attack escalated enormously. The conspirators were at work again.
At the moment there was nothing to be done.
Resolutely Spock returned to the command console.
"Mr. Chekov, set a course for Rura Penthe."
At the helm Chekov swiveled to face the Vulcan. "Mr. Spock, Rura Penthe is deep within Klingon territory. If we're discovered-was" Quite right, Mr. Chekov, "Spock allowed smoothly before the helmsman could finish.
"If, as I suspect, all of our computer data banks have been stripped of all information on the Klingon language, then we will have to rely on the archive library. What is now required is a feat of linguistic legerdemain-and a degree of intrepidity-before the captain and Dr. McCoy freeze to death."


I cannot say anything about the in-universe reason why Spock has not ordered Uhura to prepare for the conversation in advance.  However, I have a clear memory of that scene from when I saw Star Trek VI in the theater during its original run.  The scene played out that same way in the theatrical release is it does on my much-later DVD copy of the film with Chekov saying:  "A universal translator would be recognized."
I remember it specifically because it was one of the things that we discussed after leaving the film.  There was some debate as to what would have made the universal translator readily recognizable.  I thought that it was probably that the translator did not do a perfect job of reproducing the sound and rhythm of a natural speaker's voice; in other words, the smooth delivery we typically saw in the shows and movies was not representative of what listeners actually heard when someone spoke through a translator.  However, some of the other people I saw the film with had different ideas.

Or it could just be as simple as "the Universal Translator gives everyone a very particular accent" — like if it always translated into English with Received Pronunciation.  People would probably be careful not to use that accent for 'security' communications.

@Chronocidal Yes, that is one natural way in which is might "not do a perfect job of reproducing the sound and rhythm of a natural speaker's voice."
